# io.Copy() erase the Reader content

Tags: go

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
    )

    func main() {
        file, err := os.Open("HelloWorld")
        if nil != err {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()

        fileTo, err := os.Create("fileTo")
        if nil != err {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()

        _, err = io.Copy(fileTo, file)
        if nil != err {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fileByteOne, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
        if nil != err {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(fileByteOne)
    }
```

io.Copy() will erase the file content, the output is :

```
[]
```

Copy(dst Writer, src Reader) copies from src to dst, it will erase the src content. Is there 
any way to avoid erasing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `io.Copy(fileTo, file)` will erase the file content

It won't. But it will move the read position to `EOF`, meaning the next `ioutil.ReadAll()` will start at ... `EOF`.

You could close it and re-open '`file`'before your `ioutil.ReadAll()`.

By the way, you have two `defer file.Close()` instances: the second one should be `defer  fileTo.Close()`.
Or, simpler, reset it with a [`SectionReader.Seek()`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#SectionReader.Seek), as suggested by [PeterSO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221700/peterso)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23261181/6309).

```golang
 _, err = file.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
```

It is also illustrated in [GoByExamples Reading Files](https://gobyexample.com/reading-files):

> There is no built-in rewind, but `Seek(0, 0)` accomplishes this.

(`os.SEEK_SET` is define in [os constants](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-constants), as `0`)

```golang
const SEEK_SET int = 0 // seek relative to the origin of the file
```

Now (2020) deprecated and replaced with `io.SeekStart`.
See also "[Golang, a proper way to rewind file pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42245306/6309)".

Comment: `os.SEEK_SET` is deprecated, use `io.SeekStart` instead.

Comment: @MaxPeng Thank you. I have edited this 6 years-old answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Reset from the end of the file to the start of the file with a seek. For example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("HelloWorld")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    fileTo, err := os.Create("fileTo")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer fileTo.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(fileTo, file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    _, err = file.Seek(0, os.SEEK_SET) // start of file
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fileByteOne, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(fileByteOne)
}
```

Output:

```
[72 101 108 108 111 44 32 87 111 114 108 100 33 10]
```

Comment: I missed the Seek() call. +1. I have referenced it in my own answer, with a link to a "Go By Example" page.