# Golang, a proper way to rewind file pointer

Tags: file, go, io

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    data, err := os.Open("cc.csv")
    defer data.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    s := bufio.NewScanner(data)
    for s.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(s.Text())
        if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    // Is it a proper way?
    data.Seek(0, 0)
    r := csv.NewReader(data)

    for {
        if record, err := r.Read(); err == io.EOF {

            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(record)
        }

    }
}
```

I use two readers here to read from a csv file.
To rewind a file I use  `data.Seek(0, 0)` is it a good way? Or it's better to close the file and open again before second reading.

Is it also correct to use `*File` as an `io.Reader` ? Or it's better to do `r := ioutil.NewReader(data)`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Seeking to the beginning of the file is easiest done using [`File.Seek(0, 0)`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek) (or more safely using a constant: `File.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)`) just as you suggested, but don't forget that:

> The behavior of Seek on a file opened with O_APPEND is not specified.

(This does not apply to your example though.)

Setting the pointer to the beginning of the file is always much faster than closing and reopening the file. If you need to read different, "small" parts of the file *many* times, alternating, then *maybe* it might be profitable to open the file twice to avoid repeated seeking (worry about this only if you have peformance problems).

And again, [`*os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) implements [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), so you can use it as an `io.Reader`. I don't know what `ioutil.NewReader(data)` is you mentioned in your question (package [`io/ioutil`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/) has no such function; maybe you meant [`bufio.NewReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewReader)?), but certainly it is not needed to read from a file.

Comment: I don't understand because the signature of ```Seek``` is ```Seek(offset int64, whence int)``` and constant are related to whence value so it must be ```File.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)``` not the opposite.