# Why does seeding and generating a random number prevent bufio scanner from reading lines in a file in Go?

Tags: go

I have a program which generates a random number between 1 and the number of lines in a file - call that number n. It then reads the file until iterator i == n and then prints that line from the file.

I'm seeing very strange behaviour though which I'm struggling to explain. For some reason, when I allow my code to seed and generate a random number, the bufio scanner fails and does not print the name from the file. When I comment the number generation part out, the exact same code works and a name is printed as expected.

In the below code, commenting and un-commenting the code between the hashtags inexplicably changes the behaviour of the bufio scanner code - and by that I mean it either prints or doesn't print a name from the file.

The file I refer to is just a list of names e.g.

name1
name2
name3

NOTE:
go version == 1.16.3 darwin/amd64

Code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open(nameFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    // ############## RANDOM NUMBER GENERATION ##############
    // min := 1
    // max, err := lineCounter(f)
    // if err != nil {
    //  log.Fatalln(err)
    // }

    // rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    // v := rand.Intn(max-min) + min
    // fmt.Println(v)
    // ############## RANDOM NUMBER GENERATION ##############

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    i := 0
    for scanner.Scan() {
        i += 1
        if i == 60 {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func lineCounter(r io.Reader) (int, error) {
    buf := make([]byte, 32*1024)
    count := 0
    lineSep := []byte{'\n'}

    for {
        c, err := r.Read(buf)
        count += bytes.Count(buf[:c], lineSep)

        switch {
        case err == io.EOF:
            return count, nil

        case err != nil:
            return count, err
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang, a proper way to rewind file pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245227/golang-a-proper-way-to-rewind-file-pointer) your "random number generator" process reads the entire file (or at least a large enough buffer), leaving the file pointer at the end.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco It does indeed. I completely missed that my lineCounter function reads the whole file to get it's length in lines to set an upper bound for the random number. So adding f.Seek(0, 0) before the bufio.NewScanner() fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Use [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to pick a random line from a file in a single pass over the file.

Comment: The reservoir-sampling method is indeed the way to go: it sidesteps not only this missing seek problem, but also the problem of reading from a single-pass stream (e.g., a pipe rather than a file). When your desired sample size is 1, the complexities all vanish and you can use a trivial algorithm.

Comment: Reservoir sampling implementation: https://play.golang.org/p/Lgv1Rzr47l2

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be simplified way, way down:

```
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "io"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   f := strings.NewReader(strings.Repeat("north\n", 9))
   io.ReadAll(f)
   s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
   for s.Scan() {
      println(s.Text())
   }
}
```

So as you can see, it's nothing to do with the random numbers, and it's not even anything to do with a file. When you are calling that "bad function", you're reading up all the data in the reader, so nothing is left for the `Scanner` to use.